# Add my GCM code into exisiting app

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the code http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ It is running well for multicast too.I want to remove the user registration activity from the app and integrate it into my existing app.How to do that?
The GCM  is taking email id and name from the users.I don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the app you linked to, the RegisterActivity is the first activity started when the app is launched, and it doesn't do anthing beside asking for email and name, and starting the MainActivity.

You can simply remove this activity and start the app from the MainActivity.
That means you should add the following intent-filter to the declaration of MainActivity in the manifest, and remove the declaration of RegisterActivity.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

In the code of MainActivity.onCreate you should remove any reference to email and name (which are currently passed to it from the RegisterActivity). The registration to GCM is already done in the MainActivity, so you don't have to change anything there.

That said, you are basing your app on an old tutorial (from 2012) which uses a deprecated class (GCMRegistrar) to register to GCM. You should look at the current [official GCM Demo app](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/java/com/google/android/gcm/demo/#demo%2Fapp) to see how the current way of registration looks like. It's simpler.

Comment: Ya the code worked,but it is not able to register new ones.No new registration is being done.

Comment: I used my phone,not emulator.The app is not running in any of my AVD.It shows 
[2014-07-14 00:31:40 - AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2014-07-14 00:31:40 - AndroidPushNotificationsUsingGCM] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.androidhive.pushnotifications/com.androidhive.pushnotifications.RegisterActivity} does not exist.
 ON CONSOLE

Comment: @Varshita But RegisterActivity is the activity you wanted to remove.  Did you remove it from the manifest?  Are there any other places in your code referring to that class?

Comment: It worked.I kept register activity and used Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class); in it.In manifest i used register activity only.I also removed all the references of email id and name from register actitvity.

Comment: I want to send notification to more than 5000 devices.The same code will work for that?

Comment: @Varshita I didn't look at the server side code, but in order to send the same notfication to more tahn 5000 devices, you must split the registration IDs to groups of 1000 ids, and for each group send a request with 1000 registration IDs.